# Why is this dereference being ignored Cpp inline asm

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

Im kinda new to assembly and Im working on a little personal project just to learn.
Im writing my code in C++ using Visual Studio 2019.
The thing is that when I try to use the inline assembler (__asm) the dereference operator (I dont know if its called like that in assembly aswell) seems to ignore hard coded addresses.
When I write say:

```
sub[ecx + 0x08], eax
```

It works as expected, it takes the value stored in eax, substracts it from the value that is in address ecx + 8 and stores it on that address.

The thing is that when I write something like

```
mov edi, [0x5f4fa]
```

And I debug my program it just reads the instruction as

```
mov edi, 0x5f4fa
```

Can someone explain my why is this happening and how to make it work as intended? (take the value in that address and store it in edi rather than storing that address in edi).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not familiar with visual studio, but try `mov edi, dword ptr [0x5f4fa]`. Of course in general you would not be using hardcoded addresses anyway.

Comment: Already tried it and I get the same outcome

Comment: Try forcing it with specifying the data segment like `ds:[0x5f4fa]`